# 'events_statements_summary_by_digest table' is missing

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.6

In my MySQL **5.6.27** default installation the **'events_statements_summary_by_digest'** table is missing in the 'performance_schema' database.

In fact, I think more tables are missing. Did I something wrong during the installation? How can I fix this?

```
use performance_schema;
show tables;
+----------------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_performance_schema                 |
+----------------------------------------------+
| cond_instances                               |
| events_waits_current                         |
| events_waits_history                         |
| events_waits_history_long                    |
| events_waits_summary_by_instance             |
| events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name |
| events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name    |
| file_instances                               |
| file_summary_by_event_name                   |
| file_summary_by_instance                     |
| mutex_instances                              |
| performance_timers                           |
| rwlock_instances                             |
| setup_consumers                              |
| setup_instruments                            |
| setup_timers                                 |
| threads                                      |
+----------------------------------------------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Did you run `mysql_upgrade` after updating to 5.6.27?

Comment: I think the table was added in 5.6.5.  And other changes have been made to the P_S since then.

Comment: The tables listed are from MySQL 5.5, not 5.6. Run mysql_upgrade (see @RickJames answer)

Answer (score 1):

The changelog for 5.6.9 says

"If you upgrade to this release of MySQL from an earlier version, you must run mysql_upgrade (and restart the server) to incorporate this change into the performance_schema database. (Bug #14075527)"

`events_statements_summary_by_digest` was added in 5.6.5.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer :( It was a new clean installation of MySQL. I will try to run the mysql_upgrade during the weekend (it's a production environment). Thank you!